# How to grab child attribute using Selenium Webdriver with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to grab an attribute of a child. I inspect my element in Chrome, and see the following code for it:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <ion-label style="text-overflow: ellipsis; display; block; overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;" class="label label-md" id="lbl-80" producttypeid="39553">Item 1</ion-label>
```

The attribute that I need is "producttypeid".

When I right click on the first row and choose its selector the following command gives me nothing:
  `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("cssFromChrome").get_attribute("producttypeid")`

When I right click on the second row and choose its selector, the selector that I get is `#lbl-80` which is not good for me since it is dynamic, and I need something static to grab that element.

What else can I try to grab that attribute?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is regex match if `id` will always uniquely start with `lbl-`

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("ion-label[id^='lbl-']").get_attribute("producttypeid")
```

Another option is to use the child

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".input-wrapper > ion-label").get_attribute("producttypeid")
```

Comment: I tried it both ways, but every time I get "none" as a result.

Comment: Try if you are able to get any other attribute. Seems to be straightforward, not sure why it doesn't return the value.

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML if you want to extract the `producttypeid` attribute of the child you can write a function as follows :

```
def get_producttypeid(myString):
        print(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='producttypeid']/ion-label[@class='label label-md' and starts-with(@id,'lbl-')][.='" + myString + "']").get_attribute("producttypeid"))
```

Now, from you can call the `get_producttypeid()` method with the required item description e.g. **Item 1** to retrieve the `producttypeid` attribute as follows :

```
get_producttypeid("Item 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'lbl') and contains(text(), 'Item 1')]").get_attribute("producttypeid")
```